# maketitle is undefined for articles in a suftesi book

Tags: suftesi

I have started to use suftesi for a book with multiple articles and tried with the minimal example from section 5:

```
\documentclass[structure=collection]{suftesi}
%process with pdflatex 

\begin{document}    
    \input{articleTest}
\end{document}
```

and a single article copied from the manual:

```
\begin{article}
\author{Author}
\title{Title of the paper}
% The abstract is optional.
% \begin{abstract}
% The abstract
% \end{abstract}
\maketitle
Text of the paper
\end{article}
```

This produces with pdflatex the error

```
Undefined control sequence. \maketitle
```

what must be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually `\maketitle` that is undefined I think, your editor probably did a bad job parsing the error message. The complete error I get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@maketitle ...{title.\thearticle }\Hy@raisedlink 
                                                  {\hyper@anchorstart {\@cur...
l.20 \maketitle

?
```

The macro that caused the error is therefore `\Hy@raisedlink` (last macro before line break in error message), which is used in `suftesi`s definition of `\maketitle`. That macro is defined by the `hyperref` package, so adding

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

solves the problem. (At least on my system.)

I added the missing `\` before `begin{article}` by the way, I assume that was a copy-paste mistake.

```
\documentclass[structure=collection]{suftesi}
%process with pdflatex 
\usepackage{hyperref} % <-- add this

\begin{document}    
\begin{article}
\author{Author}
\title{Title of the paper}
% The abstract is optional.
% \begin{abstract}
% The abstract
% \end{abstract}
\maketitle
Text of the paper
\end{article}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick solution. It works - perhaps the suftesi package should indicate that `hyperref `is required. (I fixed the question for the missing slash before the first begin. It was indeed dropped during copy-paste.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that this is a bug in `suftesi`, which can be solved by doing a further check:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-test.tex}
\begin{article}
\author{Author}
\title{Title of the paper}
% The abstract is optional.
% \begin{abstract}
% The abstract
% \end{abstract}
\maketitle
Text of the paper
\end{article}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[structure=collection]{suftesi}
%process with pdflatex

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\@maketitle}
   {%
    \xdef\@currentHref{title.\thearticle}%
    \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
   }
   {%
    \@ifundefined{Hy@raisedlink}{\let\texorpdfstring\@firstoftwo}{%
      \xdef\@currentHref{title.\thearticle}%
      \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
    }%
   }
   {}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\input{\jobname-test}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents` environment has been used just for making the example self-contained.

If `\Hy@raisedlink` is not defined, we can assume `hyperref` has not been loaded (the `\@ifundefined` is performed when all packages have been loaded); in this case we define `\texorpdfstring` to return its first argument; otherwise, the same code as the current `suftesi` is executed.